# Why does my Nokia 2.2 screen light keep coming on even in my pocket?

Tags: screen, nokia

I have Nokia 2.2 updated to Android 11. Why does its screen light keep coming on even in my pocket?

I have turned off "tap to wake" and it comes on when I even touch the phone.